# Using Magento as a CMS for a Fanfiction Archive

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, custom, cms

I was doing research on CMSs and talking to a few people about using Magento for use as a fanfiction archive similar to Fanfiction.net or Archiveofourown.org

the folks I talked so were unsure about a definitive yes or no because I had to explain what a fanfiction archive was and what it does.

A fanfiction archive is a website where users register accounts so they can post their writings/stories for others to read, IE other registered users or even non registered visitors to the site.  Though registration is often needed to use site features like the ratings system, to write reviews, Private message the author or other users, etc.

fanfiction, which is defined as fiction written by a fan of, and featuring characters from, a particular TV series, movie, etc. is stored in the archive and usually in vast amounts, often searchable through keyword search, user name search, title search and/or the use of a tagging system to find the content you want. IE. (You want to find romance stories you would search under the 'romance' tag, you want to search for a particular character you would search the character's name tag 'John Doe' etc.)

Now in my research people have suggested using wordpress as a fanfiction archive, however that's only because it's been done before to varying levels of success. My question could Magento be used for this purpose? Could it do it well? and if so, I feel that this could be a novel use for it because as far as I can see, no one has tried yet. (I like being a trail blazer.)

-Charles

Answer (score 2):

Magento is an ecommerce system, not a social platform. If you want to sell products, you're in the right place. If you don't, there are almost certainly better options.

You could use the Magento platform for what you describe, but you would be building out almost all of the functionality custom.